# Problem saving state with set in react hook when loading data from an API?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

My idea is that when someone put a text in my TextInput and clicks submit then `botToc()` will save the data from that API search in `result` and show the `result` in a FlatList.

But I have a problem saving data with hooks. The thing is that my `setResult` is not working properly because it does not save well the data from the API query. `botToc()` is supposed to fetch data from an API and its doing that fine but then I loop through the fetched data and I save what I want in `result` using `setResult`.

The thing is that when I click the button that uses `botToc2()` ( after clicking the button that uses `botToc()` ) my `console.log(result)` shows only the data of the last element and if I use again `botToc()` and I click one more time `botToc2()` I get that last element duplicated in the `result` array.

How can I fix this?

```js
export default function TestScreen () {

    const [querypar, setQuerypar] = useState('');
    const [apipar, setApipar] = useState('https://API/search?q=');
    const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

    const ItemView = ({item}) => {
      return (
          <View>
            <Text>
              {item[0]+ '  ' + item[1]}
            </Text>
          </View>
      );
    };

   function botToc() {
      let query = apipar+querypar;  //'https://API/search?q='+'TextInputText'
      let cargador = [];

      fetch(query) //'https://API/search?q=TextInputText'
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then( res => {
        // (res.results) = [{price:x,title:x},{price:x,title:x},{price:x,title:x}] structure of (res.results)
        (res.results).forEach( (element) => {
            cargador.push(element.title);
            cargador.push(element.price); //cargador=[x,x]
            setResult([...result, ...cargador]); //result=[[x,x],[x,x]...]
            cargador.length = 0; //cargador=[]
        });
      })
   };


   function botToc2() {
    console.log(result); //my console should return [[x,x],[x,x],[x,x],[x,x],[x,x],[x,x],...]
   };

    return (
      <View View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput placeholder="write here" onChangeText={(val) => setQuerypar(val)} />
        <View>
            <Button onPress={botToc} title="Submit"/>
            <Button onPress={botToc2} title="Submit"/>
            <FlatList
            data={result}
            renderItem={ItemView}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `setResult()` multiple times in the *forEach* function should be avoided. In that case your `botToc()` function should look like this:

```
    function botToc() {
      let query = apipar+querypar;  //'https://API/search?q='+'TextInputText'
      let cargador = [];

      fetch(query) //'https://API/search?q=TextInputText'
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then( res => {
        // (res.results) = [{price:x,title:x},{price:x,title:x},{price:x,title:x}] structure of (res.results)
        (res.results).forEach( (element) => {
            cargador.push([element.title, element.price]); //cargador=[x,x]
        });
      })
      setResult(cargador);
   };
```

This should do the job for you.

Comment: Well that did the job but why cant i call setResult() multiple times? Whats the logic behind?

Comment: @knownothingjonsnow , you can call `setResult()` multiple times but this is not a good practice in React, because each time a state is set, the component get re-rendered. So, multiple `setState` call should be avoided. 

And, in case of your error, I think you did not get the error for the `setResult()` call. Rather it was for the syntax inside the `setResult([...result, ...cargador])` call.